# SQL: How to select a count of multiple records from one table, based on records in a different table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, join, count

Let's say I have two tables:

**TABLE A**

MessageID | Message

1 | Hello
2 | Bonjour

etc..

**TABLE B**

CommentID | MessageID | Comment

1 | 2 | This is a comment to someone saying Bonjour
2 | 2 | This is another comment to Bonjour

What I'm trying to do is run one query that pulls all the records from Table A ("the messages") along with a count of all the comments for each message from Table B.

The result would be:

**Hello - 0 comments

Bonjour - 2 comments**

I know this is probably some combination of using a join with a count(*), but I can't seem to hit on just the right syntax.

Any ideas?

Comment: Thank you all for your help. This works:    `SELECT *, count(commentID) as commentcount  
FROM tableA LEFT JOIN tableB  ON tableA.messageID = tableB.messageID   GROUP BY message`  but....how would I go about getting **ALL** the records from TableA, with just the addition of a commentcount from TableB? I get a MSSQL "Column 'tableA.messageID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause" error when I try to select * from TableA.

Comment: Sorry, the above should be `SELECT message, count(commentID) as commentcount
FROM tableA LEFT JOIN tableB ON tableA.messageID = tableB.messageID 
GROUP BY message`   Using the * gives me the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a message based approach:

```
SELECT message, count(commentID) 
FROM tableA LEFT JOIN tableB ON tableA.messageID = tableB.messageID 
GROUP BY message
```

You'll want a LEFT JOIN to include records in Table A that don't have any comments in Table B.

Comment: This works: `SELECT message, count(commentID) as commentcount FROM tableA LEFT JOIN tableB ON tableA.messageID = tableB.messageID GROUP BY message` but how would I get **all** the records from tableA and just the count from tableB?

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
SELECT a.MessageID, COUNT(*)
FROM TABLEA a
JOIN TABlEB b
ON b.MessageID = a.MessageID
GROUP BY a.MessageID
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
SELECT MessageID, COUNT(CommentID)
FROM "TABLE B"
GROUP BY MessageID
```

If you need Message in addition to MessageID, you should be able to do something like this:

```
SELECT MessageID, MIN(Message), COUNT(CommentID)
FROM "TABLE A" LEFT JOIN "TABLE B" USING (MessageID)
GROUP BY MessageID
```

*(Oracle syntax, probably same for MSSQL)*

Answer (score 0):

Just an addendum to what's already posted since, if you're using this for a scripting language, you'll likely need named columns for everything in the SELECT list:

```
SELECT tableA.messageID, message, count(commentID) AS commentCount
FROM tableA LEFT JOIN tableB ON tableA.messageID = tableB.messageID 
GROUP BY message
```